# MLE $\hat{h(\mu)} = h(\hat{\mu})$ of $h(\mu) = var(Y_1) = \mu^2$

Tags: self-study, estimation, maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution

**Question**: Suppose Y1, · · · , Yn follows an Exponential distribution with $\lambda = \frac{1}{\mu}$. Derive the MLE $\hat{h(\mu)} = h(\hat{µ})$ of $h(µ) = var(Y_1) = µ^2$, and show that $h(\mu)$ is not unbiased for $h(\mu) = \mu^2$.

**Attempt**: I've found that the MLE for $f(y;\lambda = \frac{1}{\mu})$ is $\hat{\mu} = \bar{y}$. Since the variance of an exponential distribution is $\lambda^2 = \frac{1}{\mu^2}$, do I perform the same steps? This [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/318794/maximum-likelihood-estimator-for-square-of-lambda-in-poisson-distribution) states something about $(\lambda^2)_{mle}=(\lambda_{mle})^2$.

Comment: The MLE of a one-to-one transform of the parameter $\theta$ is the transform of the MLE of $\theta$. indeed, since the likelihood function involves no Jacobian for a change of parameterisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [functional invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#/Functional_invariance), and the transformation doesn't have to be *one-to-one.* So, $\hat{h}(\mu)=\bar{y}^2$. If you take the expectation and do the algebra it won't be equal to $\mu^2$, so will be biased.